# shiny The application unexpectedly exited

Tags: r, shiny

I made shiny application on my local machine which is completely working. I face the pop-up error message "The application unexpectedly exited. Diagnostic information has been dumped to the JavaScript error console." when I deployed my app on server with shiny-server.

I checked JavaScript error console. But nothing special message. Very normal message like,

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:46683
Loading required package: DBI

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

filter
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

I tried some edit to solve this problem. Finally I found that 'observe()' and 'updateSelectInput()' function may cause this error. The error pop-up appears when my server.R has

```
observe({
vars <- input$input1 * 1:100
updateSelectInput(session = hoge, inputId = "input2", choices = vars, selected = vars[1])
})
```

The pop-up error does not appear when this function is not in my server.R

Is that bug of shiny-server? If not, how can I avoid this pop-up error message?
If you have any solution for this problem, please let me know.

my shiny is 0.11.1.9005 and I installed shiny-server from source.

Best,

Comment: Would be interested in this answer as well.